# Multiple aggregates from same sub query in SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, join, subquery

Is there a better way of doing this without having the repeated sub queries that just select a different field?

```
SELECT Name, er.DateEventStarts, e.LocationName,
(SELECT count(*) FROM Ticket t WHERE t.Deleted = 0 AND Refunded = 0 AND t.EventRepetitionID = er.EventRepetitionID) AS NoOfAttendees,
(SELECT sum(t.TicketTotalCost) FROM Ticket t WHERE t.Deleted = 0 AND Refunded = 0 AND t.EventRepetitionID = er.EventRepetitionID) AS NoOfAttendees,
(SELECT sum(t.OnlinePayFee) FROM Ticket t WHERE t.Deleted = 0 AND Refunded = 0 AND t.EventRepetitionID = er.EventRepetitionID) AS OnlinePayFee,
(SELECT sum(t.OnlinePayTotalCost) FROM Ticket t WHERE t.Deleted = 0 AND Refunded = 0 AND t.EventRepetitionID = er.EventRepetitionID) AS OnlinePayTotalCost  
FROM [Event] e
JOIN EventRepetition er ON er.EventRepetitionID = (SELECT TOP 1 EventRepetitionID FROM         EventRepetition er2 WHERE er2.EventID = e.EventID)
```

As you can see the sub queries are almost the same but just sum or count a different row.  I feel there must be a better way of doing this but can't see how else to do it.  I imagine this is probably not very efficient.

I apologise if this has already been answered but I just cannot think of a way to describe this problem so was unable to search for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    er.DateEventStarts,
    e.LocationName,
t.NoOfAttendees,
t.TotalTickets,
t.OnlinePayFee,
t.OnlinePayTotalCost  
FROM [Event] e
JOIN EventRepetition er
    ON
        er.EventRepetitionID = (SELECT TOP 1 EventRepetitionID FROM EventRepetition er2 WHERE er2.EventID = e.EventID)
join
    (select EventRepetitionID,COUNT(*),SUM(TicketTotalCost),SUM(OnlinePayFee),SUM(OnlinePayTotalCost)
    from Ticket
    where Deleted = 0 and Refunded = 0
    group by EventRepetitionID) t (EventRepetitionID,NoOfAttendees,TotalTickets,OnlinePayFee,OnlinePayTotalCost)
        on
            er.EventRepetitionID = t.EventRepetitionID
```

This should only scan the ticket table once.

Comment: Ah yes of cause :)  It seems so obvious now, but I just couldn't think of anything at the time.  Thanks for this, it is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested the next one, but it will be something like this:

```
select Q.name, Q.ateEventStarts, Q.locationName,
        count(*), sum(T.TicketTotalCost), sum(T.TicketTotalCost), 
        sum(T.OnlinePayFee), sum(T.OnlinePayTotalCost)
    from ( 
        select Name, er.DateEventStarts, e.LocationName, er.EventRepetitionID
            from Event e JOIN EventRepetition er on er.EventRepetitionID = 
                (select top 1 EventRepetitionID from         
                    EventRepetition er2 where er2.EventID = e.EventID) ) Q
    left outer join Ticket T
        on t.Deleted = 0 and T.Refunded = 0 
            and t.EventRepetitionID = Q.EventRepetitionID
```

Comment: Yes that would work if you wrapped the Q.name, Q.DateEventStarts and location name with Max().  I was hoping there was a way to somehow select a table within the query and then do the aggregates on it but I guess that's not the way SQL server work.  I don't understand why you added an extra sub query though going into Q.  Is that just to make it neater?

Comment: The subquery is there for the case that the join with Ticket returns more than 1 row for each row in Q. If it returns more than 1 row (say n), the count and sums will return n times the value if you do this without the subquery Q.